# Using UUIDField in Django keeps creating new migrations

Tags: django, uuid

I have a simple model::

```
class HasUUID(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
      batchid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), unique=True)
```

running makemigrations gives me the migration::

```
   operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='HasUUID',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('batchid', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('79a2d9fe-e1d0-4d4b-884f-fad0bfb14f0f'), unique=True)),
        ],
    ),

]
```

Running migrate gives me the new table no problem.  But I can run makemigrations again and I get::

```
    operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='hasuuid',
        name='batchid',
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('3b96231c-5848-430b-aa90-b6e41b11fd0a'), unique=True),
    ),

]
```

and while I have lived with this for a while, manually removing the unnecessary code, I need to resolve it.

so I think, make the default a separate function in the migrations as shown in various examples::

```
def create_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
      m = apps.get_model('web', 'HasUUID')
      for inst in m.objects.all():
          inst.batchid = uuid.uuid4()
          inst.save()

...

  migrations.CreateModel(
       name='HasUUID',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('batchid', models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True)),

        ],


    ),
    migrations.RunPython(create_uuid),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='hasuuid2',
        name='batchid',
        field=models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    ),
```

same problem.  So I tried making the default a separate function in the model::

```
  def create_uuid():
      return uuid.uuid4()


  class HasUUID2(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
      batchid = models.UUIDField(default=create_uuid(), unique=True)
```

and this gets me this migration::

```
  migrations.CreateModel(
        name='HasUUID3',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=10)),
            ('batchid', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.UUID('335c3651-b04e-4ed8-a91d-f2da3f53dd8f'), unique=True)),
        ],
    ),
```

and again, keeps generating new migrations.  I've also tried without the unique = True.

I'm out of ideas.  There must be some settings or code elsewhere as I have used UUID fields before and I cannot find a similar problem on stackoverflow.  Any suggestions?

Comment: even if you pass a callable the a migration will be generated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass the callable as default, not the result of a call, like:

```
class HasUUID(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
      batchid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

Notice that there are *no* paratheses here to make the call, we thus pass a reference to the `uuid4` function itself.

The `default=` value is *not* a specific UUID (that is determined when you *start* the server), it should be a value that is determined when you create a new object (without specifying the `batchid` yourself).

By passing a callable, Django will understand that the default is the result of a call to the callable, and it will encode that in the migration. By calling the function, you retrieve the *result* of the call, and each time you run `makemigrations`, Django will think that you changed your mind on what should be the default value (it will first think you want to use `'3b96231c-5848-430b-aa90-b6e41b11fd0a'` as default, and later that you want to use `'335c3651-b04e-4ed8-a91d-f2da3f53dd8f'`). By passing a callable, the value you pass as default remains the same.

Comment: I wonder what happen with existing rows do they will be updated or you have to do it manually with an empty migration?

Comment: It creates unique id.

Comment: @santhosh_dj: what do you mean? It will create a unique idea yes, or at least that is extremely likely, UUID collisions are very unlikely, but can happen.